# use github release for npm package install

Tags: npm

I'd like to install this package

https://github.com/Yuri-Lima/woocommerce-rest-api-ts-lib/

but I need the 7.0.1 release. not the official 7.0.0 which is in the npm repository.  I'm not used to getting special release with npm.

I tried a number of npm install variants but none have worked or give me an error code 2 (i'm on windows)

```bash
npm install https://github.com/Yuri-Lima/woocommerce-rest-api-ts-lib.git
```

etc.

Anything that seems like it almost works, gives an error type 2 (Cannot find module 'woocommerce-rest-ts-api' or its corresponding type declarations.).

How do i accomplish this?

---

Error example:

```bash
PS D:\git_projects\myapp> npm install github:Yuri-Lima/woocommerce-rest-api-ts-lib#v7.0.1
npm WARN deprecated package.json@0.0.0: Use pkg.json instead.
npm ERR! code 2
npm ERR! path D:\git_projects\myapp\node_modules\woocommerce-rest-ts-api
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c tsc --outDir ./build
npm ERR! ../../src/app/api/wooc/product_categories/route.ts(14,52): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'woocommerce-rest-ts-api' or its corresponding type declarations.
npm ERR! ../../src/app/api/wooc/products/[id]/route.ts(3,52): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'woocommerce-rest-ts-api' or its corresponding type declarations.
npm ERR! ../../src/app/api/wooc/products/route.ts(3,52): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'woocommerce-rest-ts-api' or its corresponding type declarations.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-14T14_21_49_779Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to  [npm install documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-install) you can follow such format to install the required package with a specific version:

```
npm install github:<githubname>/<githubrepo>[#<commit-ish>]
```

in your case your command would be:

```
npm install github:Yuri-Lima/woocommerce-rest-api-ts-lib#v7.0.1
```

Comment: This just gives me the error code 2 result, see append on original post.

Comment: hmm actually i made a new test app and tried to install it this way and it works. so i guess there is something wrong with my node/npm/typescript setup in my main app.